# c# console application, excel data to dictionary to use for sql query

Tags: c#, sql, excel, import

I have a program that currently prints an excel worksheet in console, but I would like to be able to store that information to then put it into an SQL table.

How would I go about using gets and sets for this?

I have 2 classes.

Program.cs

```
class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\praktikant\source\Console\KPIimport\KPIimport\KPI_Bestyrelsen.xlsx");
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;


        object[,] valueArray = (object[,])xlRange.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
        String[,] arr = new String[rowCount, colCount];
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++) {

                if (j == 1)
                    Console.Write("\r\n");


                if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null) {
                    //Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
                    arr[i, j] = valueArray[i, j].ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }

        //cleanup
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();


        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

        //close and release
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

        //quit and release
        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }
}
```

and Items.cs which I haven't used because I simply don't have any idea

```
class Items {
    public DateTime Dato { get; set; }

    public string Portal { get; set; }

    public decimal Home_oms { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why did you create Items.cs? where is your code to connect and communicate with the database?

Comment: @Markus
The database connection isn't important right now, the important part is for me to store the excel data somewhere so I can insert it later, me writing the sql thing was only to give some context to what i wanted to do with it

Comment: you are already storing it in the "dictionary"

Comment: Yes but it's not sorted with keys so I don't know how to use it for a query